# Unable to get response from BroadcastReceiver Class in android Studio? How can I trace error No errors detected

Tags: android-studio, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I developing a simple android app, in which I am trying to get the incoming SMS.
I search alot tutorials and write all codes , no errors with code but not getting any required result also.
I start new project, add new class and extends it with BroadcastReceiver and write all mendatory method(like onReceive)in this class. I write Toast statment for testing. No errors or warning found during compiling. but unable to get responce of code written in BroadcastReceiver Class.(even toast is not displaying) 
I didn't write any thing on Main activity. 
I also write all permitions in mainifiset file like sms read write and receive and receiver code also.
Do I have to make any link between MainActivity and this new class.
Please help me...

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String message ="";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                     message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                    // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                            "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();


                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```

and mainifest file have these entries

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Adding code would be helpful for us to help you!

Comment: Please Help someone..